# What is the standard way to center labels in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I have some code like so that I was hoping each text line to be centered (instead it was left justified).  (I just downloaded latest upgrade of codenameone and intellij yesterday and am starting to play with codenameone).  I meant to a long time ago and got distracted.

```
    super("MyApp", BoxLayout.y());

    add(new Label("Welcome to the world"));
    add(new Label("of"));
    add(new Label("Games"));
```

Here is a picture from the codenameone simulator...

[image]

I tried to tweak the very first label to this

```
    Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the world");
    label1.setTextPosition(Component.CENTER);
    add(label1);
```

but that throws an Exception "Text position can't be set to 4".  I tried a Container with BorderLayout after that doing an addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("Welcome")) but that ended up left justified as well.

Any ideas how to fix this to be centered?

EDIT: I found a deprecated label.setAlignment method.  That fixes the alignment to be centered.  Is this maybe a bug in the latest release?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the alignment property of styling via designer, CSS or `Style` object to one of `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `CENTER`.

`setTextPosition` only works in relation to the icon. So if you want the text on the left and the icon on the right you can set it to `RIGHT` or even `BOTTOM` to put it under the icon.

There is one important caveat. Alignment only works within the box you're placed in so this is only applicable when the component itself is big enough.

Another common pattern to align anything is using flow layout e.g.: `Container centered = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(myCmp);`